# Workaround for new Edge Indexeddb bug?

Tags: javascript, performance, microsoft-edge, indexeddb

Microsoft released update kb4088776 in the past couple days, which has had a devastating effect on performance of indexedDb openCursor.

The simple fiddle here shows the problem. With the update, the "retrieval" time is 40 seconds or more. Prior to the update, it is around 1 second.

https://jsfiddle.net/L7q55ad6/23/

Relevant retrieval portion is here:

```
var _currentVer = 1;
function _openDatabase(fnSuccess) {
    var _custDb = window.indexedDB.open("MyDatabase", _currentVer);

    _custDb.onsuccess = function (event) {
        var db = event.target.result;
        fnSuccess(db);
    }
    _custDb.onerror = function (event) {
        _custDb = null;
        fnSuccess(null); // should use localData
    }
    _custDb.onupgradeneeded = function (event) {
        var db = event.target.result;
        var txn = event.target.transaction;

        // Create an objectStore for this database
        if (event.oldVersion < _currentVer) {
            var customer = db.createObjectStore("customer", { keyPath: "guid" });
            var index = customer.createIndex("by_id", "id", { unique: false });
        }
  };
}


function _retrieveCustomers(fn) {
  _openDatabase(function (db) {
    if (db == null)
    {
      alert("not supported");
      return;
    }
    var customers = [];
    var transaction = db.transaction("customer", "readonly");
    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("customer");
    if (typeof objectStore.getAll === 'function') {
      console.log("using getAll");
      objectStore.getAll().onsuccess = function (event) {
        fn(event.target.result);
      };
    }
    else {
      console.log("using openCursor");
      objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function (event) {
        var cursor = event.target.result;
        if (cursor) {
          customers.push(cursor.value);
          cursor.continue();
        }
        else {
          fn(customers);
        }
      };
    }
  });
}
```

[image]

The time to create and add the customers is basically normal, only the retrieval is bad. Edge has never supported the getAll method and it still doesn't after the update.

The only workaround I can think of would be to use localStorage instead, but unfortunately our data set is too large to fit into the 10MB limit.  It is actually faster now to retrieve from our servers and convert the text to javascript objects, defeating the main purpose of indexeddb.

Comment: So, I guess you're asking for an alternative workaround?

Comment: you should fill a bug on edge. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/

Comment: yes, honestly the workaround we may have to go with is downloading from our server every time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Edge so I can't test this, but does it happen with `get` too, or just `openCursor`? If `get` still performs well, you could store an index (in your example, the list of primary keys; in your real app, maybe something more complicated) in localStorage, and then use that to call `get` on each one.

Comment: Interesting. get seems to perform normally, at least to human sensitivity but doing it 10,000 times may prove to be just as slow.

Comment: I tried to implement this here but I lack the patience to wait for it to finish. Even in Chrome, too slow: https://jsfiddle.net/L7q55ad6/31/

Comment: I think that's queuing up too many operations at once, try https://jsfiddle.net/L7q55ad6/43/ - at least on my computer, performance is reasonable (a bit faster in Firefox, a bit slower in Chrome)

Comment: this is promising. In Edge it is even faster than the pre-update version. Of course, I have sparse keys in the real data but I'll see if I can make that work, probably saving a list in localstorage as you said.

Comment: correction, on the "updated" Edge, using get is even slower. On the non-updated it is slightly faster. I had installed the update and got mixed up which state my computer was in. Nice trick for some cases but unfortunately won't help me.